# How to encrypt a number?

Tags: mysql, encryption

Is there a specific best practice for encrypting numbers in MySQL, like financial figures? For example, I would naturally store an invoice amount as a DECIMAL(22,2) but I need to keep the exact amount secret from the database administrators.

(The same philosophy applies to DATE and DATETIME values.)

I'm assuming that I simply pass the data to the encrypt function as a string, and store it as a string, and then convert the decrypted data back to the required number data type when I retrieve. Is this acceptable?

Comment: You can use any algorithm for encryption you want, as long as the details required for that (the secret key or whatever) is _not_ available on that system whose administrators you are afraid of. Otherwise whatever you try is senseless. So use a local encryption setup and store the resulting string in the remote system (database).

Comment: crypt the hole table or database. then also every dump is crypt. see : https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/table-and-tablespace-encryption-mariadb-101

Comment: I can't encrypt the whole database or even whole tables – the administrators need to be able to see primary keys, indexes and timestamps.